# Optimizing MS SQL insert via pyodbc

Tags: json, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am capturing JSON response from an API call and inserting into MS SQL db. There are about 500,000 total data entries from the API that I can query 1000 at a time.

The SQL insert query statement seems to be taking too long and I am assuming it may have something to do with my query concatenation and string conversion.

**SQL columns**

```
self.query_headers = "([ac_serial_reg_key],[activity_date], 
    [aircraft_delivery_date],[activity_name],[activity_remark],
    [aircraft_category],[aircraft_financial_status],[aircraft_group],
    [aircraft_model],[aircraft_operational_status],[aircraft_registration_number], [aircraft_serial_number],
    [aircraft_type],[engine_model],[engine_type],[operator_name]
)"
```

**The SQL values are then combined by iterating the JSON response**

```
self.query_values = ''

for idx, set in enumerate(self.response.json()['results'], start=1):
    self.query_values += "("
    self.query_values += "'"+str(set['aircraft_registration_number'])+"_"+str(set['aircraft_serial_number'])+"',"
    self.query_values += self.validate_date(set['activity_date'])+","
    self.query_values += self.validate_date(set['aircraft_delivery_date'])+","
    self.query_values += "'"+str(set['activity_name'])+"',"
    self.query_values += "'"+str(set['activity_remark'])+"',"
    self.query_values += "'"+str(set['aircraft_category'])+"',"
    self.query_values += "'"+str(set['aircraft_financial_status'])+"',"
    self.query_values += "'"+str(set['aircraft_group'])+"',"
    self.query_values += "'"+str(set['aircraft_model'])+"',"
    self.query_values += "'"+str(set['aircraft_operational_status'])+"',"
    self.query_values += "'"+str(set['aircraft_registration_number'])+"',"
    self.query_values += "'"+str(set['aircraft_serial_number'])+"',"
    self.query_values += "'"+str(set['aircraft_type_lar'])+"',"
    self.query_values += "'"+str(set['engine_model'])+"',"
    self.query_values += "'"+str(set['engine_type'])+"',"
    self.query_values += "'"+str(set['operator_name'])+"'"
    self.query_values += ")"                    

if idx < self.response.json()['results_this_page']:
    self.query_values += ","
```

How do I best parse the returned JSON objects to create a single (or many) insert statement?

**Insert statement**

```
self.query = "INSERT INTO "+self.database+" "+self.query_headers+" VALUES"+self.query_values
self.cursor.execute(self.query)
self.cnxn.commit()
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother; i'd send the JSON to the DB as a NVARCHAR(max) and get the DB to unpack it - it will certainly be faster than unpacking 500,000 json entities in your client app and running half a million insert statements.

Comment: Definitely worth investigating, @CaiusJard Got a reference link for me to understand how to do that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 is pretty good, to help out more, post some example json and a table spec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the link in my comments, something like this can quickly insert hundreds of thousands of json values into a table:

```
JSON: 
N'[  
       { "id" : 2,"info": { "name": "John", "surname": "Smith" }, "age": 25 },  
       { "id" : 5,"info": { "name": "Jane", "surname": "Smith", "skills": ["SQL", "C#", "Azure"] }, "dob": "2005-11-04T12:00:00" }  
 ]'
```

You'd parameterize your SQL script so your front end app populates the @json variable (I don't know what this looks like in python, sorry, but it's the same as any parameterized sql). Here's the script

```
INSERT INTO Person(id, fn, ln, age, dob, skill)
SELECT *  
FROM 
  OPENJSON(@json)  
  WITH (id int 'strict $.id',  
        firstName nvarchar(50) '$.info.name', 
        lastName nvarchar(50) '$.info.surname',  
        age int, 
        dateOfBirth datetime2 '$.dob',
        skills nvarchar(max) '$.info.skills' as json) 
  OUTER APPLY 
    OPENJSON( skills ) --to "recurse" into the skills array
    WITH( skill nvarchar(8) '$' )
```

It would be important to note that the outerapply will cause the person data for Jane Smith to repeat, once per skill:

```
5, Jane, Smith, ..., C#
5, Jane, Smith, ..., SQL
5, Jane, Smith, ..., Azure
```

Maybe your json doesn't have this structure. if it does you can either leave it packed (don't outer apply) or strip out uninteresting things with a WHERE:

```
INSERT INTO Person(id, fn, ln, age, dob, skill)
SELECT *  
FROM 
  OPENJSON(@json)  
  WITH (
         ...
        skills nvarchar(max) '$.info.skills' as json) 
  OUTER APPLY 
    OPENJSON( skills ) --to "recurse" into the skills array
    WITH( skill nvarchar(8) '$' 
WHERE skill = 'C#'
```

Comment: SPOT ON! The second video tutorial on this page is worth the price of admission. Its probably 1/4 the time of constructing the string query method I had. 


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017